# meaning of a red dot on border of window

Tags: org-mode, display

This entry was created using `org-capture` and removing 'TODO'. I wonder why it shows a red dot in the lhs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red mark indicates the presence of a bookmark.  `org-capture` leaves this when it is done (the bookmark is called `org-capture-last-stored`).  See the [manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-capture.html) for more.